# Replacement of compute by clause in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i have been working on query which uses compute by clause for avg and sum operators .
As Microsoft declared this will be a discontinued feature ,what will be the replacement for this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708.aspx) which is part of the [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause

Comment: This should come with a note that makes it clear that the consumer of the results will have to change. If you have a program that expects `COMPUTE`-style multiple result sets, `ROLLUP` won't give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly (although this might be a bug), the [SQL Server 2005 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190452(SQL.90).aspx) says

> The COMPUTE and COMPUTE BY clauses are
>   provided for backward compatibility.
>   Instead, use the following components:
>
> SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services
>   (SSAS) with OLE DB for Analysis
>   Services or Microsoft ActiveX Data
>   Objects Multidimensional (ADO MD). For
>   more information, see Analysis
>   Services Data Access Interfaces
>   (SSAS).
>
> The ROLLUP operator. For more
>   information, see Summarizing Data
>   Using ROLLUP.

but the (later) [SQL Server 2008 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190452.aspx) merely says

> The COMPUTE and COMPUTE BY clauses are
>   provided for backward compatibility.
>   Instead, use the following components:
>
> SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services
>   (SSAS) with OLE DB for Analysis
>   Services or Microsoft ActiveX Data
>   Objects Multidimensional (ADO MD). For
>   more information, see Analysis
>   Services Data Access Interfaces
>   (Analysis Services - Multidimensional
>   Data).

I don't know if the omission of ROLLUP in the latter is a mistake, or if that means it's not longer a suggested way forward.

Comment: If you look at SQL 2008 COMPUTE link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708.aspx it says ROLLUP